# SQL-Statement for counting and calculating relational data

Tags: sql, relation

I have a main-table "Restaurants" and an one-to-many relation to a "RestaurantVotes" table. One Restaurant can have multiple Votes. It's defined like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `restaurant_votes` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `user_id` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `cat_food` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `cat_cart` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `cat_ambassador` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `cat_drinks` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `cat_service` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `cat_ambience` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `cat_price` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `restaurant_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `IDX_1B96C91EB1E7706E` (`restaurant_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_1B96C91EB1E7706E` FOREIGN KEY (`restaurant_id`) REFERENCES `restaurants` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `restaurants` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

For an API-call we need to get all restaurants including name and the overall rating for this restaurant as a JSON response. Name etc. is no the problem, but we have big problems to find a SQL-query which gets the rating for each restaurant. The rating is calculated like this:

1. Summerize the values (integer 1-5) of all categories (cat_*) and divide it by the number of the categories (7).
2. Summerize the result of the ratings above and divide the value by the number of ratings in the restaurant_votes table per restaurant.
3. Return the overall rating from 2. in the SQL-query together with the name of the restaurant.

Is this even possible using SQL? Any advice? Thanks!

Comment: Well, what have you tried?

Comment: Do you have to have it in a single statement?  Which scripting language are you using to produce the JSON or is your SQL server providing JSON responses directly?

Comment: Nothing in raw SQL. We use the symfony2 framework for our webapp and used the included QueryBuilder. But we can't access a custom property for calculating the rating in the QueryBuilder. The dataset consists of ~5000 entries, so we need to exclude many fields from the restaurant-table due to performance issues (i removed most of the fields in the sql above). And that's the reason why we just can't use readymade functions like findAll() etc.

Comment: I thought a single statement is the only way, as we don't know much about writing raw sql statements…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select 
r.name, 
sum(rv.cat_food + 
    rv.cat_cart +
    rv.cat_ambassador +
    rv.cat_drinks + 
    rv.cat_service +
    rv.cat_ambience +
    rv.cat_price) / 7 as total_score, 
sum(rv.cat_food + 
    rv.cat_cart +
    rv.cat_ambassador +
    rv.cat_drinks + 
    rv.cat_service +
    rv.cat_ambience +
    rv.cat_price) / 7 / count(rv.id) as average_score
from   restaurants r
left join restaurant_votes rv
  on r.id = rv.restaurant_id
group by r.name
```

I've posted a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/712dd/12) to demonstrate this.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT r.name,r.id,score.rating
FROM 
restaurants as r
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT restaurant_id,AVG(cat_food + cat_cart + cat_ambassador + cat_drinks + cat_service + cat_ambience + cat_price)/7 AS rating
FROM restaurant_votes
GROUP BY restaurant_id
)as score
ON r.id = score.rating
```

Would this work?
It gets all the restaurants defined in the restaurant table and and gets the average of all the columns added together and divided by 7.

Comment: Chose the other solution. Thanks. But you get a vote for thinking about it.